# Security Exception calling Reporting Services from a Windows Service

Tags: wcf, reporting-services, windows-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to call the web service for SQL Server Reporting Services from a Windows Service.  I can successfully make the call from an Asp.Net MVC website, but when I try to use exactly the same code from a Windows service (with seemingly the same WCF configuration), I get the following error...

> Inner Exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException
>   - The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.
>
> Inner Exception: System.Net.WebException - The remote server returned
>   an error: (401) Unauthorized.

BOTH the application pool for my Asp.Net MVC site AND the Windows Service are set up to use the "Network Service" user.

Here is my WCF configuration in the config file...

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment
        aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxDepth="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
                    />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
      </security>
    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://myserver/ReportServer_MSSQL2008/ReportExecution2005.asmx"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportExecutionServiceSoap"
      contract="ReportService.ReportExecutionServiceSoap" name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" behaviorConfiguration="ImpersonationBehaviour" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
   <behavior name="ImpersonationBehaviour">
    <clientCredentials>
     <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="None" allowNtlm="true"/>
    </clientCredentials>
   </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I have tried all the different "allowedImpersonationLevel" and have tried it without this behaviour defined at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make you have referenced all codes need to run the windows app at som point.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I understand your answer.  Please could you explain what you mean?